# Applications frequently become permanently unresponsive

Tags: performance, macos

I frequently have applications become unresponsive while they're in the background. That is, I'm not able to switch back to them*, and the Force Quit Applications window shows them as "Not Responding". They never become responsive again no matter how long I wait.

Some features that make this problem unusual:

- It's not limited to one or two applications. It's happened with MS Office applications, Textedit, BBEdit, Evernote, OpenOffice, Preview, and others.
- It's not limited to times when the application is doing something intensive. In fact, it usually happens to apps that have been in the background and not doing anything in particular.
- I've never observed it to happen to web browsers or to music players that are playing music.
- It doesn't seem to be triggered by other applications doing things that are CPU or memory-intensive.
- Other applications are not slowing down or hanging when it happens.
- The non-responding application shows < 1% CPU usage in Activity Monitor.
- If I force quit the application and restart it, then the problem usually doesn't recur quickly.

Does this suggest any potential causes or troubleshooting steps? I know the usual advice is to either start with a new account or disable all of my other programs and customizations one by one, but I'm hoping that the specific features of this problem might help me proceed in a more targeted way.

System info: 
Macbook Pro, 2012 model, OS 10.9.4, 8GB RAM, 500GB HDD with 160GB free

* Specifically, what I mean is that I can cmd-tab to the application's icon, but the program in the foreground doesn't change. If I expose one of its windows, I can move the window around, but clicking in it doesn't bring the application to the foreground or affect the contents of the window. Notably, I do not get the beachball / pinwheel pointer when hovering over it, as I do in other cases when an application is stuck.

**update**:

[Here's the system log from an incident when OpenOffice became unresponsive](https://gist.github.com/octern/3cc3bb4287fcde2d79a4). I discovered it at 8:17. I don't know exactly when it failed, but the last log message and the last revision time on my auto-saved files is 7:46, so I assume it was within 5 minutes of that. Note that the OpenOffice error in the log (appears as `soffice`) shows up twice, five minutes apart, meaning that the first one wasn't fatal and so I suspect the second wasn't the cause of the hang either.

Comment: A detailed Console report would help to maybe see what is happening. Use a stuck application name to search your Console data base for your report.

Comment: Is that the problem of your Mac OS? Have you ever reinstalled OS for your Mac?

Comment: @Buscar웃 There don't seem to be any log entries related to the stuck applications.

Comment: If you would be so kind and publish a log anyway, you might have missed something in it.

Comment: I'll do that next time I catch it -- as is so often the case, asking for help with the problem seems to have made it temporarily disappear.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I've added a log.

Comment: Thanks, will be reading it today. There is one non-fatal that has to do with Preview? and bunch of errors with the connection...

Comment: Could you also look/Publish this one "Submitted crash report: file:///Users/hibounce/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2014-09-10-220724_healslime.crash" from whom is that?

Comment: Preview was crashing when I tried to paste an image from the clipboard. It didn't resemble the problem with apps hanging, and it doesn't seem to be recurring now.

Comment: The 3 finder crash reports are for my user account. I don't recall seeing anything unusual happen at the time. They were, in order, SIGSEGV, SIGBUS, and SIGSEGV. I don't see anything else in there that I'm able to interpret. In my DiagnosticReports folder I have reports for clusters of 3-4 crashes like that every few days in the past couple of weeks.

Answer (score 1):

OK,

I will work with you on this step by step.

First to eliminate the following:

```
process plugin-container[1362] caught causing excessive wakeups. EXC_RESOURCE supressed due to audio playback
9/11/14 7:58:33.000 AM kernel[0]: process firefox[1359] caught causing excessive wakeups. Observed wakeups rate (per sec): 163; Maximum permitted wakeups rate (per sec): 150; Observation period: 300 seconds; Task lifetime number of wakeups: 61563
```

These messages are triggered by a plugin that you're running.

Go to Tools : Add-Ons : Plugins (in Firefox), and one-by-one, for each plugin listed, please do the following:

1) Disable the plugin.
2) Restart Firefox and check if you still see the message.

- **Update and part 2:**

Your Preview is generating lots of problems?

Lets start with obvious.

> Open Preview:
>
> File,
>
> Open Recent,
>
> Clear Menu

*The reason: There seems to be a croup file in your Preview.*

Comment: The culprit appears to be Flash. I have it set to request permission on all sites, and the error reliably appears about 30 seconds after permitting it on one of the pages I use frequently. I will refrain from using it and see if that helps.

Comment: Preview hasn't been consistently causing problems, just this morning. I went ahead and cleared the recent files menu.